# How to obtain a device android token with new Firebase Cloud Message

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, token

I'm having trouble getting the device token to the notification specifies a device. I'm doing everything I ask the tutorials on the net, including the official guide of Firebase, but I can not get in the log the device token. Would anyone out there can help it?

Gradle (project):

```
...
//firebase CM
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
..
```

Gradle (app):

```
...
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.packapps.firechat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainChat"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <!-- new Services -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Class:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Log.i("LOG", "entrou em onTokenRefresh");
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("TAG", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken) {
    }

}
```

Comment: can you paste your full manifest here

Comment: Done Shubhank. The receipt of notifications is normal. Just be the token service that is not doing anything.

Comment: it isnt usually called if a token has been generated. Try deleting app and re installing the app to check

Comment: Perfect, is working ok ! Thanks Shubhank!